# Square Connect CreateCheckOut Swift

Tags: swift, deep-linking, square, square-connect

I have the API running properly, and I get the `checkout_page_URL` back from `CreateCheckout`, but I don't know where to go from there because the documentation/StackOverflow seems to point to Square products that my business doesn't use.

I'm simply using CheckOut (no POS, no Reader, etc.).

With that said, do I still use the iOS App URL scheme under the POS API (Square Developer dashboard)?

What's the preferred method to get a user to the `checkout_page_URL`, and then, most importantly, a return back to my app after successful completion of the transaction?

Is it simply using the Connect `redirect_url` parameter?

If so, does Square Connect support iOS deeplinking?

Comment: Typically the `Checkout` API is meant for web apps/websites, not mobile applications. For directing the user to the `checkout_page_URL`, you would use whatever method it is to open a browser providing the URL. I do not believe deep linking works to open the mobile app.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question. Include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve], plus any error messages. Ask specific questions. Most people are happy to help, but don't want to do your work for you. Questions like "how do I do x?" that don't show any research effort on your end are likely to get ignored.

Comment: Sjosey, thx, so what solution should I be using for a mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

Upon further inspection, Square doesn't make sense for the workflow I'm trying to accomplish so thx sjosey for setting me straight. Looks like Stripe is the best fit for my project.

Comment: I am using squreup, is possible bulk import products with qty, no issue in products import but inventory only not update, did you ever face this issue? @Ben